# After installing with pip, -bash: Jupyter: command not found

Tags: python-2.7, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I had installed 'brew' first, then python with brew. Finally, I entered "pip install jupyter --user" to have it installed. Then I typed "Jupiter notebook" and it says "command not found". I've tried this several times already, looking up the webs to identify problems and solve but I can't seem to understand this problem. I am new to Mac as well as python and programming language. So please help me in finding and solving the problem with running Jupyter? Thank you.
*p.s. below I have attached the image file of the terminal screen for your reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxB6r.jpg)

Comment: jupyter is installed in the "user" directory `~/.local/bin` make sure it is in your path by adding `export PATH=${HOME}/.local/bin:${PATH}` to your `~/.bashrc` file and restarting the console.

Comment: thanks for the input, but could you show me what exactly I have to enter in the terminal? I'm a noob so please bear with me ;(

Comment: `open -e ~/.bashrc` in the terminal, then add the line `export PATH=${HOME}/.local/bin:${PATH}`, save the file and restart the terminal.